# Get Graphics from KML Layer in ArcGIS JS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, kml

I just started working with the ArcGIS Javascript API and I was wondering how I would go about getting an array of Graphics from a KML layer. I do not know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

The [KML with buffer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_kmlbuffer.html) sample shows exactly what you're requesting.